# Access specific kubernetes pod from external

Tags: kubernetes

I have a replication controller creating 10 instances of my pod. The pod runs a Zeppelin notebook which should be accessed by users over the web. However I need the possibility to access a specific notebook/pod over the web. If I expose the pods using a service of type LoadBalancer I will automatically be routed to any pod.

Is there a way to expose an extra IP per pod or another way to access specific pods over the web? Or is the only way to create 10 replication controllers and 10 services?

Comment: The use case makes no sense...why do you want specific access?

Comment: Thats not the question, but: each pod also has a local spark-cluster and each user shall have a similar, dedicated 4 core environment. Therefore it matters that each user can access his pod.

Comment: So you are looking at multi-tenancy?

Comment: We will implement a multi-tenancy-able Zeppelin-Spark cluster setup in the medium term, however that's not what this question asks for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 1:1 IP addresses you'd need a replication controller for each site.  Replication controllers are for managing identically configured resources.

However, you could always do [host-based or path-based](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#simple-fanout) routing to get to the right service / pod. That way you could just have a subdomain + mapping for each user.

Comment: Well, the resources are identical (the same Docker image), but I also think there is no other way

Comment: The Lord Gave, and the Lord Hath Taken Away! Check the updated answer, might have what you need

Comment: Ingress is indeed a good idea to prevent having multiple external ideas, however it does not prevents the requirement to create a rc and a service per notebook, it even adds an additional component.

Comment: That's true, but to do exactly what you want you'll need to write a service that interacts with the Kubernetes API, creating RCs from a template and regenerating the Ingress object. To my knowledge there isn't anything in the kubernetes core that will do this for you, though there very well could be a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Another option a colleague of mine just came up with is to create an own namespace per needed replication and deploy the same replication controller and service into those. That's at least a bit more comfortable and offers a higher level of isolation.